# Create large amount of products in magento from mysql

Tags: mysql, magento

Is there any short and fast way to create large amount of products in magento from mysql ?

Comment: directly feed in database is not correct way. you can use import instead

Answer (score 0):

My script allow to convert csv to SQL queries. It not creating products, images , relations yet, but allow to import mostly all other data. 100000 products in a minute https://github.com/ShaurmaLab/MagentoImport

follow us and watch for updates soon